# What does 'Normalized Solar Intensity' refer to in the diagram below

Tags: visible-light, wavelength

For the Value Axis (Normalized Solar Intensity) what does the value represent? Is it the Solar Irradiance rate normalized in a specific equation or is it something else?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Normalized here means the values are scaled so that the highest is one and the lowest is zero.

No other magic involved.

Comment: With something like the solar spectrum we're usually more interested in the relative intensity of different wavelengths rather than the absolute intensity.  The solar spectrum shown is valid anywhere at approximately sea level when the sun is approximately overhead.  To give specific units, one would need to precisely define where and when it is valid (latitude, time of year, time of day etc.).